# Live555 RTSPServer object destroyed improperly or the library bug?

Tags: c++, rtsp, live-streaming, live555

I have a problem with destroying `RTSPServer` object: the app crashes with a `SIGSEGV` Error. But the `RTSPServer` object might be destroyed only in the case if I do not touch all other objects. 
Is this a library bug or am I doing something wrong?

Their recent [live555 changelog](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/public/changelog.txt) says:

```
2015.05.12:
- Updated the previous revision to change the order in which fields are deleted 
  in the "RTSPServer" destructor, to avoid a possible crash if "RTSPServer" 
  objects are deleted. (Thanks to ChaSeop Im for noting the problem.)
```

This is my destructor:

```
RTSPServerH264::~RTSPServerH264()
{
    LOG(INFO) << "RTSP server close: destroying objects";

    if (mSms.size() > 0)
    {
        LOG(INFO) << "destroying: Server Media Subsession vector";
        for (ServerMediaSession* s : mSms)
        {
            s->deleteAllSubsessions();
            Medium::close(s);
        }
        mSms.clear();
        mLiveSubsession.clear();
    }

    if (mRTSPServer)
    {
        LOG(INFO) << "destroying: RTSPServer";
        // BUG: Destroying RTSPServer object crashes the whole application!
        Medium::close(mRTSPServer);
    }

    if (mUsageEnvironment)
    {
        LOG(INFO) << "destroying: Usage Environment";
        mUsageEnvironment->reclaim();
    }

    if (mTaskScheduler)
    {
        LOG(INFO) << "destroying: Task Scheduler";
        delete mTaskScheduler;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to my question is now available here:
http://lists.live555.com/pipermail/live-devel/2015-June/019490.html

Response text:

> > I have a problem using `Medium::close()` in my destructor when deleting an `RTSPServer` object after I have already deleted
> >     `ServerMediaSession*` objects vector (of course, using `Medium::close()`
> >     too).
>
> First, make sure that you are using the latest version of the software
>   (a bug related to deleting `RTSPServer's` was fixed in version
>   2015.06.24).
>
> Second, be aware that once you have added a `ServerMediaSession`
>   object to a `RTSPServer`, you must *not* delete the
>   `ServerMediaSession` object by calling `Medium::close()`.  Instead,
>   you must use `GenericMediaServer::deleteServerMediaSession()`
>   (`GenericMediaServer` is the base class of `RTSPServer`), so that the
>   `RTSPServer` is told that the `ServerMediaSession` object is being
>   deleted.
>
> Finally, however, note that you don’t need to delete
>   `ServerMediaSession` objects before you delete a `RTSPServer`, because
>   the `RTSPServer` destructor will automatically delete any
>   `ServerMediaSession` (and `ClientConnection` and `ClientSession`)
>   objects that it manages.  Instead, you can just call `Medium::close()`
>   on your `RTSPServer` object.
>
> Ross Finlayson, 
>   Live Networks, Inc., 
>   http://www.live555.com/